# Why is my option for deployment target missing in Android Studio 3.5?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

This is what I see when I go to Run...Edit configurations...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDuae.jpg

Currently my Android Studio deploys to whatever device is plugged into it, or the emulator if nothing is plugged in.  it used to ask every time and I really want to reset it.

I poked around the Configuration Folder:https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

but it isn't obvious to me what needs to be changed.

Does anyone know how I can get those options back?  or what config file I need to edit?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you have disabled the Firebase Testing plugin in Android Studio.